# R remove values that do not fit into a sequence

Tags: r

I have a sequence `s` where I expect each proceeding value to be either the same as the previous one or +1.

```
s = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,-2,3,3,4,8,8,8,9,5,5,12,6)
```

What I want:

```
1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6
```

I've solved this with the following code:

```
counter = 2
repeat{
  
  if(s[counter] == s[counter-1] | s[counter] == s[counter-1]+1){
    counter = counter+1
  } else{
    s = s[-counter]
  }
  
  if(counter >= length(s)) break
}
```

which however appears quite 'dirty' and inefficient. Is there a computationally less time-consuming solution?

Comment: FYI, this is not about `data.table`: even if `s` were a column in a `data.table`, the solution would be vector-based.

Comment: I can't think of a way to vectorize this in R, but it seem like it would lend itself very well to an Rcpp solution. How much efficiency do you need? If your complaint is only "elegance", I think your solution is pretty okay (though you could save the row-deletion for the end), but if you need speed Rcpp will be lightning quick.

Comment: @GregorThomas the real vectors are extremely long and I have quite a lot of those. My solution seemed computationally inefficient and time consuming. That's why I was curious about a more efficient (and in my eyes perhaps also more "elegant" solution). But I admit "elegance" is not the focus here. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't see an easy vector based solution, but a normal for loop with preallocation could help here

```
s = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,-2,3,3,4,8,8,8,9,5,5,12,6)
increasing_seq <- function(x) {
  keep <- logical(length(x))
  current <- x[1]
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i] == current) {
      keep[i] <- TRUE
    } else if (x[i] == current + 1) {
      current <- current + 1
      keep[i] <- TRUE
    }
  }
  x[keep]
}
increasing_seq(s)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6
```

Here we avoid recreating the `s` vector of different sizes. It's normally re-allocation that's slow, not looping.

Comment: I burrowed the idea to preset the keep vector to FALSE instead of TRUE and now are solutions are pretty much identical. I guess I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 12):

This can be done with `Reduce`:

```r
Reduce(function(prev, this) 
  c(prev, if (any(this %in% (prev[length(prev)] + 0:1))) this),
  s)
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6
```

This can't be vectorized since the calc on one position relies on the results of the previous calculations, but this is compact and (imo) readable.

FYI, if performance is your primary metric, then it appears sindri_baldur's Rcpp and MrFlick's current answers win out by a landslide:

```r
bench::mark(
sindri_baldur = {
  keep      = vector(length = length(s))
  keep[1]   = TRUE
  last_keep = 1L
  for (counter in 2:length(s)) {
    if ((s[counter] - s[last_keep]) %in% c(0, 1)) {
      last_keep = counter
      keep[counter] = TRUE
    }
  }
  s[keep]
},
sindri_baldur_rcpp = s[foo(s)],
r2evans = {
  Reduce(function(prev, this) 
    c(prev, if (any(this %in% (prev[length(prev)] + 0:1))) this),
    s)
},
MrFlick = increasing_seq(s))
# # A tibble: 4 x 13
#   expression              min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result     memory     time     gc       
#   <bch:expr>         <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>     <list>     <list>   <list>   
# 1 sindri_baldur        2.62ms   3.05ms      317.   37.81KB     15.5   143     7    450.5ms <dbl [13]> <Rprofmem~ <bench_~ <tibble ~
# 2 sindri_baldur_rcpp      1us    1.4us   533120.    2.49KB      0   10000     0     18.8ms <dbl [13]> <Rprofmem~ <bench_~ <tibble ~
# 3 r2evans              28.5us   36.9us    23454.   24.67KB     18.8  9992     8      426ms <dbl [13]> <Rprofmem~ <bench_~ <tibble ~
# 4 MrFlick               2.1us    2.5us   345770.        0B      0   10000     0     28.9ms <dbl [13]> <Rprofmem~ <bench_~ <tibble ~
```

Comment: This is a cool idea, it's just the `c()` part is killing the performance I would bet. Too many re-allocations.

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm not as convinced; an alternative that doesn't explicitly use `c(.)` performs the same: `s[s == Reduce(function(prev, this) if (any(this %in% (prev + 0:1))) this else prev, s, accumulate = TRUE)]`. I suspect the slowdown is just as likely due to overhead in `Reduce`, the cost of using a more general approach.

Comment: could the sindri_baldur_rcpp code be added, or am I looking at it and failing to recognize?

Comment: `sindri_baldur_rcpp = s[foo(s)],` is there, perhaps refresh your page? @Chris

Comment: With a longer test case like
`s = ifelse(runif(2000) < 0.1, round(runif(2000) * 1000), rep(1:100, each = 20))` only the rccp one is competitive (at about 500 times faster).

Comment: No doubt, @CongChen, but we don't know to which scale we should be optimizing. If the vectors are relatively short (under 100), then a base-R solution might be simpler to maintain (depending on the user).

Comment: Agreed, just noting the enquirer mentioned the actual data was 'extremely long' so I thought I'd try for longer test cases.

Comment: I see it now in a comment, yes. Perhaps OP should have put that in the question itself, I find comments unreliable for retaining/communicating key points like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

*Edit*

R concept translated to Rcpp:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('LogicalVector foo(NumericVector s) {
  int n = s.size();
  Rcpp::LogicalVector keep(n);
  keep[0]  = 1;
  int last = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if        (s[i] - s[last] == 0) {
      keep[i] = 1;
    } else if (s[i] - s[last] == 1) {
      keep[i] = 1;
      last = i;
    } 
  }
  return keep;
}')


s[foo(s)]
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6
```

---

*Original solution (very similiar but inferior to MrFlick's)*:

Another slightly more efficient R loop. However, if efficiency is important Rcpp might be a good choice.

```
keep      = vector(length = length(s))
keep[1]   = TRUE
last_keep = 1L
for (counter in 2:length(s)) {
  if ((s[counter] - s[last_keep]) %in% c(0, 1)) {
    last_keep = counter
    keep[counter] = TRUE
  }
}
s[keep]

# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

First, order the vector `s`.

```
s <- s[order(s)]
```

Then find the differences between the neighbouring elements of `s` that less than or equal to 1.

```
d <- diff(s) <= 1
```

Next, find a vector that counts consecutive TRUE values within `d`.

```
t <- ave(d, cumsum(!d), FUN = cumsum)
```

Last steps, find the maximum value of `t` and its index.

```
vmax <- max(t)
imax <- which(t == vmax)
```

Hence, the desired vector is

```
s[imax - vmax + 1 : imax + 1]
```